# Javascript click on query selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, click, html-lists

Here is javascript code.

```
document.querySelectorAll("li[class='user selected']")
```

I wanna click on this element but this code does not work

```
document.querySelectorAll("li[class='user selected']").click();
```

How can I click on this element ?
Thanks.

Edit : this is Html code

```
<ul class="search" id="typeahead_list_u_0_2" role="listbox">
<li class="user selected" title="Special Username" aria-label="Special Username" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="js_g">
<a href="https://..." rel="ignore" target=""><img alt="" src="https://...">
<span class="text">Special Username</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` will return you array of selected element. Not the first match. Use `querySelector` instead

Comment: Actually it works fine when I want to return first element but the problem is click event, I can not click .

Comment: If you add HTML code, i can have a look at it and can suggest. Try to put the code in fiddle and share it.

Comment: I have updated html code, do you want me to add more html codes ?

Comment: This is good enough. So, at time, you will have only one `li` element with class `user selected` ? Or many `li` elements will have that class ?

Comment: I fill names and get users. But I fill full name so I only get one element which is "user selected"

Comment: Then you can use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`. I am updating the answer with a sample click listener.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the sample `click` listener that i have attached.

```js
var element = document.querySelector("li[class='user selected']");

if (element) {
    
    // TODO: Attaching sample click listener. Remove it.
    element.addEventListener('click', function () {
        alert('Clicked');
    }, false);
    
    element.click();

}
```

```html
<li class="user selected" title="Special User Name" aria-label="Special User Name" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="js_x"></li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, But it does not work , I do not know what is wrong.

Comment: How are you attaching `click` listener ?

Comment: I have updated my html code again, maybe something is wrong with my code

Comment: So, you are trying to redirect the user to the URL specified in `href` of `anchor` tag ?

Comment: I am trying to add my friends into a fb group by code. I type name automatically but I can not pick or click on element.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ?

```
document.querySelectorAll("li[class='user selected']")[0].click();
```

Will click on the first  (`[0]`) `li[class='user selected']`

Comment: yeah I have tried, It does not work.  When  I try this code I get an error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of nullmessage: "Cannot read property '0' of null"stack: (...)get stack: function () { [native code] }set stack: function () { [native code] }__proto__: Error(anonymous function) ..."